# How to pass command to includedproject for build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I need to pass command like "build -x test" to included project, how to do it?
any hints will be more than welcome! , currently it is without  -x test like below

```
plugins {
  id "com.gradle.build-scan" version "1.6"
}

apply plugin: 'eclipse'

defaultTasks 'build'

//gradle build -Pfast=true 
task build{
    if(project.findProperty('fast')&&project.findProperty('fast').toLowerCase()=='true') {
        println "#### build fast###  " + project.findProperty('fast')
        gradle.includedBuild('another-project').task(':build')
    }else{
        println "#### build normally###" 
        dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('another-project').task(':test')
        dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('another-project').task(':build')
    }
}

task clean{
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('another-project').task(':clean')
}

task test{
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('another-project').task(':clean')
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('another-project').task(':test')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below wordaround will solve my problem

```
workingDir '../another-project'
commandLine 'gradle', 'build' ,'-x' ,'test'
```